# How to set Global environment variable to work directory on jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-job-dsl

I have jenkins job, where I need to use global environment variable which I have created (user defined) in global env variable.

I want to use this global variable in work directly.

I have attached the screen shot with this question.

like on the work directory I want to use
bin/release/*user_defined_variable*

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Are you asking whether you can use a variable instead of hardcoding net6.0?

Comment: yes.. and I tried to use with $VariableName, ${variableName}, ${env.variableName}, %%varibaleName%%. none of this option working for me

Comment: which plugin is this specifically? the plugin must support variable expansion. why do you need/want to parameterize?

Comment: I will confirm you with the plugins.. this is I need because of the value I am using on multiple jenkins jobs and this will change based on latest version. so instead of changing multiple places, will change only on one place